# Why is Pentium 4 Prescott slow compared to Pentium M?

Tags: cpu-speed, cpu-architecture

I was benchmarking if it is worth to put loop inside a callback function so I tested fourth order Runge-Kutta of on y'=y in C++, all with gcc 5.1 on Ubuntu with compilation command

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -march=native --fast-math test.cpp
```

## The Runge-Kutta loop

```
double dt=(t_end-t_0)/N;
auto y=y_0;
auto t=t_0;
for(size_t k=0;k<N;++k)
    {
    auto k_1=f(k*dt, y);
    auto k_2=f(k*dt + 0.5*dt, y + 0.5*dt*k_1);
    auto k_3=f(k*dt + 0.5*dt, y + 0.5*dt*k_2);
    auto k_4=f(k*dt + dt, y + dt*k_3);

    y+=dt*(k_1 + 2*k_2 + 2*k_3 + k_1)/6.0;
    }

return y;
```

Inlining was achieved by a template and a function object. For dynamic binding a function pointer was used.

## The Pentium M

### Specs as given by `/proc/cpuinfo`

```
cpu family      : 6
model           : 13
model name      : Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 1.73GHz
stepping        : 8
microcode       : 0x20
```

### Frequency from `sudo cpufreq-info`

```
current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 1.73 GHz.
                The governor "userspace" may decide which speed to use
                within this range.
current CPU frequency is 1.73 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
```

### Results

```
                  ODE solution       exp(1)             diff                   Execution time
Function pointer  2.718281828037378  2.718281828459045  -4.21667145644733e-10  53321972
Inlined call      2.718281828037378  2.718281828459045  -4.21667145644733e-10  19916460
```

## The Prescott:

### Specs as given by `/proc/cpuinfo`

```
cpu family      : 15
model           : 4
model name      : Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.40GHz
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x5
```

### Frequency from `sudo cpufreq-info`

```
current policy: frequency should be within 2.80 GHz and 3.40 GHz.
                The governor "userspace" may decide which speed to use
                within this range.
current CPU frequency is 3.40 GHz.
```

### Results

```
                  ODE solution       exp(1)             diff                   Execution time
Function pointer  2.718281828037378  2.718281828459045  -4.21667145644733e-10  70811683
Inlined call      2.718281828037378  2.718281828459045  -4.21667145644733e-10  19928642
```

## Comparison and question

So the Prescott performs no better (it seems to be much worse), than the much lower clocked Pentium M. Sure, Prescott had a very long pipeline, but my code is highly predictable since N=2^30. So what makes the Prescott that slow despite its high CPU frequency?

Comment: @DragonLord But these two machines are booth from 2005

Comment: @user877329 - Answer still applies.  The newer processors are able to perform more instructions per clock cycle, even if they have a slower clock cycle, that means more instructions will completed faster. The generation gap between some intel processors are pretty significant.

Comment: The Pentium M is a more power-efficient architecture which formed the basis for the Core 2 series. It was optimized for high performance per clock, so that good performance can be delivered with lower clock rates. Lower clock rates mean lower power consumption, especially when the difference is between 3.4 and 1.73 GHz.

Comment: @ user877329: But they are completely different otherwise. The P-mobile is derrivated from a relative efficient (for the time) CPU and optimised to do well with low power (read: lower frequencies).  The P4 was designed to run at very high speeds and much efficiency was sacrificed. The result is about the same speed for a 3GHz P4 and a P-m 740 *at 1.7GHz)

Comment: You already seemed to be aware of much of this, an image for me:
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CEbMHK8WEAAD4Ee.jpg

Comment: @Hennes I am aware of some aspects of CPU efficiency, but I never thought this particular program would suffer much, since it does not contain any evil if-statements at all. It would have been more reasonable if the Prescott performed slightly worse on an indirect call, and slightly better on an inlined call.